# Why there is still #line preprocessor directive present in a c++ preprocessed file?

Tags: c++, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I know that the job of a preprocessor is to handle all preprocessor directives of a c++ program and ready the code for compiling. But I have found #line directives are present in almost all preprocessed files. How compiler understand a preprocessor directive while compiling the code?

Comment: the preprocessor output is designed to be read by the matching compiler, how the preprocessor communicates metadata to the compiler is not defined by the c++ standard

Answer (score 1):

> Why there is still #line preprocessor directive present in a c++ preprocessed file?

Because the compiler needs information about the lines where the code used to be before the pre-processor expanded the directives. That information is used for diagnostic messages that report the exact file, line and column where the error is located.

> How compiler understand a preprocessor directive while compiling the code?

I'm not sure whether `#line` is technically a pre-processor directive or not. But the compiler understands it for the same reason it understands anything: The smart people who implemented the compiler made it work.

Comment: You're right that it's about diagnostic messages, but there's more to `#line` than preserving the original line numbering. It can also **change** the line numbering (and file naming), and that's its primary purpose. Mostly useful for compiler front ends that generate C code. When you compile the C code you want diagnostics and debug information to refer to the original source code, not the generated C code. (And, yes, it is technically a preprocessor directive)

Comment: Hi Pete Becker... I there any other such preprocessor directives like #line which still present in preprocessed file..?